# find the unique indices from list

Tags: python, list, python-2.7

I've two list

```
a = [4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
b = [4,4]
```

and the list may be like this as well

```
a = [1, 1, 1, 4, 1, 0, 0, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
b = [1,4]
```

and i need the index position in the list a for the value which is there in list b

My Expected output should( These are index position of the value)

```
output- 
 1. [0,1]
 
 2. [0,3]
```

This code is giving all index value where it matches

```
c_set = set() 
res = [] 
for idx, val in enumerate(test_list): 
    if val not in oc_set: 
        oc_set.add(val)          
    else: 
        res.append(idx)
```

but i need the lenght of index value as list b, as i mentioned in my expected output.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: I suspect that the `set()` approach is broken for your first example because you have `[4, 4]`, so the second instance of `4` would be ignored. It's not clear to me why that should give `[0, 1]` instead of `[0, 0]` - is that definitely the expected behaviour?

Comment: I am  not able to comprehend your problem, can you please explain in detail

Comment: The output doesn't adds up, what those indices represent?

Comment: You give two values each for `a` and for `b` right at the top of your question for some reason, and then you give expected outputs for, presumably, one of those cases...? Which versions of `a` and `b` are they related two?

Comment: @ roganjosh Because as you can see in my list b there are two values and i want two different index for those value.

Comment: What would happen if the element in `b` is _not_ in `a`?

Comment: @Chris then in this case it should give a empty List

Comment: output `[0,1]` what does this mean ?? i mean when `b=[4,4]`

Comment: i understood output `[0,3]` when `b=[1,4]`

Answer (score 1):

I don't see much hope in using `index()` here because your first example will give `[0, 0]` since it always returns the index of the first instance (if it exists). Instead, we can move through `a` and progressively slice the list to be searched. For each new slice, we increment an `offset` so we know how much of the list we lose each time a target is found.

We can also do a single conversion of the list to be searched into a set, for an O(1) check whether the item to be searched actually exists in the list.

```
def find(search, targets):
    
    peek = set(search)
    
    res = []
    offset = 0
    for target in targets:
        if target not in peek:
            res.append(None)
            continue
            
        for i, value in enumerate(search):
            if value == target:
                res.append(i + offset)
                offset += i + 1
                search = search[offset:]
                break
    return res

a = [4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
b = [4,4]
print(find(a, b))

a = [1, 1, 1, 4, 1, 0, 0, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
b = [1,4]

print(find(a, b))

a = [1, 1, 1, 4, 1, 0, 0, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
b = [1, 9, 4]

print(find(a, b))
```

Answer (score 1):

A bit out there but works:

```
results = [None]*len(b)
for a_index, a_elem in enumerate(a):
    for b_index, b_elem in enumerate(b):
        if a_elem==b_elem and results[b_index]==None:
            results[b_index] = a_index
            a_elem = str(a_elem)
results
```

Gives the following outputs:

1. [0,1]
2. [0,3]

It even works if you need to find out the last matching index instead of first, with a minor amendment:

```
results = [None]*len(b)
for a_index, a_elem in enumerate(a):
    for b_index, b_elem in enumerate(b):
        if a_elem==b_elem :#and results[b_index]==None:
            results[b_index] = a_index
            a_elem = str(a_elem)
results
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this work? The `try` cover the case where a value in `b` is not in `a`, which would add a `None` to the output

```
indices = []
for val in b:
    try:
        idx = a.index(val)
        indices.append(idx)
        a[idx] = None
    except:
        indices.append(None)
```

Outputs: `[0, 1]` and `[0, 3]`

EDIT: @Chris pointed out that using `None` is a better approach

Comment: @Chris good catch, been too wired in thinking with numpy lately @.@ and automatically went for it in the hopes of efficiency. After giving it a thought `a.index(val)` might be faster since it's in O(n) already

Comment: Thank You for this simple approach :)

Answer (score 0):

From my comprehension of the problem:

```
a = [1, 1, 1, 4, 1, 0, 0, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
b = [9,4]

[a.index(x) if x in a else None for x in b]
```

Output:

```
[None, 3]
```

Comment: Try this with the first example. It gives `[0, 0]`. It doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

I think this approach is more simple than others. Not sure about its performance though.

```
a = [1, 1, 1, 4, 1, 0, 0, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
b = [1,4]
resp = []


def find_from_a(idx):
    for i, v in enumerate(a, start=idx):
        yield i, v


last_idx = 0
for lookup_val in b:
    for found_idx, found_val in find_from_a(idx=last_idx):
        if found_val == lookup_val:
            resp.append(found_idx)
            last_idx = found_idx
            break

print(resp)
```

If you always need to start from the beginning, just remove the `last_idx` variable and make it always start from the beginning.